# PHP PDO error in Zend framework after a migration of a MSSQL SERVER with an error Connection

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, zend-framework, pdo, zend-db

After a planned migration of the old MSSQL Server professional to the last MSSQL Server Express version, I have a problem with the connection with an old PHP project that use Zend framework to connect on MSSQL server I suppose with PDO library.

the error message is:

> Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] Unable to connect: Adaptive Server
>   is unavailable or does not exist (severity 9)

the connection configuration is:

> Mein_Db::registry('mssql', Mein_Db::factory('dblib', array(
>              'host'      => 'xx.xx.x.xx',
>              'username'  => 'sa',
>              'password'  => 'xxxxxxx',
>              'dbname'    => 'xxxxxxx'
>          )) );

Thanks in advance,
Gianluca

Comment: Looks like you'll have to get inside of `Mein_Db` and see what's what. It's a custom class and with out the code you'll be unlikely to find much help. Check to see which adapter class `Mein_Db` is loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry but was an error of ip configuration of the MS SQL Server.
Thank to all.

Gianluca